# Hiding a box while clicking on it

Tags: php, jquery, class

I say im really newbie at this, but im trying to learn something, and im getting stucked on this fact.

Technically i just cannot hide this "homebox" when i click on it. The "click" function on this box is supposed to open a gallery...but after opening it, it should hide as well. Why? 
Because the box actually includes an image in the lower z-index, and the gallery has his images on a higher z-index, so im just having 2 images showed, and it is really bad to see.

```
<div id="homebox">
             <a href="img/gallery/Home/Harris-Wharf-London-man-01.jpg" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall16">
                         <img src="../400x550 man.png" border="0"/>
          </a>
            <?PHP
                $sql_foto = "SELECT * FROM foto WHERE idMenu = '16' ORDER BY nomeFile ASC";
                $query_foto = mysql_query($sql_foto);
                while($fetch_foto = mysql_fetch_array($query_foto))
                {
                    $foto = $fetch_foto['nomeFile']; 

                    ?>
                    <a href="img/gallery/ID16/<?PHP echo $foto;?>" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall16">
                    </a>
                <?PHP
                    }

            ?>
        </div>
```

Im trying this script in order to make this, but as i said, im trying to learn to make something cooler than the classic html site, but i suppose asking is always a good way to improve your abilities.

```
$('#homebox').click(function() {
  $('#homebox').css('visibility', 'visible') 
});
```

Thanks in advance for any constructive reply!

Comment: try $('#homebox').css('display', 'none')

Comment: refer: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: are you sure that at the time you call `$('#homebox').click(function() { ... }` the element already can be found by the query? where have you placed that query?

Comment: Are you really expecting someone to be able to open an image gallery by clicking on an invisible area of the page? Why not have your image gallery container separate from the element which controls the gallery state, then you can toggle the display of the gallery very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code...

```
$('#homebox').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

or

```
$('#homebox').click(function() {
      $(this).SlideUp();
    });
```

Comment: you should use `$(this).hide();`instead of `$('#homebox').hide();` if you are referring to the object that was clicked. Although it is really fast to query by ID there is no need to do this once again. And if the selector changes you only need to change it at one place if you use `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Please use the below code**

```
  $('#homebox').click(function() {
      $(this).hide(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#homebox').click(function() {
  $('#homebox').css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: Still no way....i dont understand if this a problem that belongs to the script or to the class..technically, i used to modify the css field "visibility" to "hidden", but it didnt work.
But if i just change the "visibility" field into the css field to "hidden" it actually hides as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `hidden` class is also a good practice. This way when browsing the DOM you can easily see which state an element has:

```
$('#homebox').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

and then in your CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; visibility: hidden; }
```

Comment: Still no way to make this work. I have no idea of whats going on here.

Comment: @SviatoslavZalishchuk You cannot use the element you are hiding to also be the trigger to hide/show it. When it is hidden, you can not click on it as it does not exist in the document flow, and click events will not fire when and element is `visibility:hidden`.

Comment: @SandorA you can do that at least once, if the element is initially visible. I showed up this example according to the question asked above. Sure, there should be the toggling trigger, or clicking on the box would only close it (like we usually do with overlay menus).

Comment: @SviatoslavZalishchuk Agree, you can do this once, but I think this part of the question 'The "click" function on this box is supposed to open a gallery...but after opening it, it should hide as well..' Shows the questioner is missing some understanding. But you are correct, it can close it one time.

Comment: Well yea...i thought it could be possible to click on this div in order to open the gallery, and once the gallery is "visible" the background image just hides, i suppose that isnt possible or it requires a lot of skill?

Answer (score 0):

You should try having separate controls for your image gallery. You cannot toggle the visibility, or display of an element by using the element itself. Once it is `visibility: hidden;` or `display:none;` it will not be firing click events, and in the case of `display: none` will not even appear in the document flow (although it will remain in the DOM).

My suggestion would be to add a gallery trigger element such as

`<a href="#" id="gallery-trigger">View Gallery</a>`

then you can add a click event to this element to toggle the visibility of your gallery.

```
document.ready(function() {
     $('#gallery-trigger').click(function() {
         $('.homebox').toggle();
     });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3leven11/h6YtJ/